# How do you validate an archetype field that is not required, but if you give it, you should validate?

Tags: validation, plone

`Products.validation` has some validators (like regex) that I would like to use in some non required fields.

So, the use case is: The validation is **required**, but **only** if the field is not empty.

How do you do it? I know I can create a custom validator, check the `REQUEST` and do all the magic, but this seens wrong to me: I should avoid creating custom code since I should just register the `RegexValidators` from `Products.validation` and use it. I tried to understand `V_SUFFICIENT` and register a regex validator using it, but isn't applicable to my situation.

I couldn't find anything on the internet, on mailing lists, on nabble, etc. So, how do you validate your fields that aren't required, but if the user provides something, you then need to validate?

I need this in a Plone 3.3.5 instance.

Comment: We simply had something similar and just run the validators externally in form submit hook instead of trying to use Archetypes for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `required = False` and your desired `validators`:

http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/archetypes/fields/fields-reference#common-field-attributes